# Laravel translate markdown mail template

Tags: php, laravel, markdown, laravel-mail, laravel-10

'How can I translate the markdown email template ?

I tried to use __() inside the template but it doesnt work.

My template :

```
<x-mail::message>
# Password

__{{'Your password is'}} : {{ $password }} // it is displaying without being translated

</x-mail::message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@lang` directive and publish your language files using `php artisan lang:publish`.

```
@lang('Your password is') : {{ $password }}
```